# Styles are not displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have written following code to print a certain div

```
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('printdiv');
var WindowObject = window.open('', "printwin", "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=400");
WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css">');
console.log(WindowObject.innerHTML);
WindowObject.document.close();
WindowObject.focus();
WindowObject.print();
WindowObject.close();
```

It is working in FF but not getting the styles from the **stylesheet** in **crome**.could you please give me any solution for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Is any javascript error is showing in Chrome?

Comment: do you mean [tag:google-chrome] ?

Comment: @issueNo329 no its not giving any error

Comment: Why are you doing `WindowObject.document.close();`?

Comment: In the network tab in Chrome dev tools, is the file being returned with a 200 response?

Comment: @Gautam3164 Have you tried to add a media type, like so: `WindowObject.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" media="print">');`

Comment: @Netsurfer yes I have tried with it but no result